# Java socket input stream blocks

Tags: java, sockets, inputstream

I've came across a problem and it's been bothering me for quite a time now. I'm working on a web server and the problem is that when i try to read the client request, the `read()` method blocks and waits for more bytes to read but there is none and the end of stream is reached which normally `read()` methods should retutn -1 but it won't until i hit the stop loading button on the browser.

```
ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(3000);
Socket s = ss.accept();
InputStream in = s.getInputStream();
int i;
while((i = in.read()) != -1){
    //some processing here
}
```

How can i fix this problem? thank you very much

Comment: Is this a binary protocol or a text protocol? It sounds like the client isn't sending what the server wants.

Comment: It's HTTP. I'm trying to read an http request from client

Comment: Then it's a text-based protocol. I'd be using a BufferedReader to read this rather than a binary stream. Unless there is an HTTPStream.

Comment: I think connection stays on because the browser is waiting for a response. this means that `read()` will not return `-1`. you should "`break` out" the loop once you've read the request and then send a response.

Comment: I used BufferedReader and still no result and ```read()``` methods blcok ...

Comment: I can't break out of the loop because the ```read()``` method blocks.

Comment: @Sako does your "processing" code execute at least once? can you show it?

Comment: @MarcoLucidi Yes i checked, as i said it reads the stream but when the end is reached is does not return -1 as it should normally and blocks, for example, let's say the length of the data is 700 bytes, it reads those 700 bytes but does not return -1 at the end and waits for more bytes which leads to the whole thread pausing and it only returns -1 when i click the stop loading button in the browser.

Comment: @Sako as i said it doesn't return `-1` because the browser is waiting for a response and the connection is still open. `-1` is returned when the **connection is closed**. the client cannot immediately close it, otherwise it wouldn't have a chance to read the response. once you have read the request (e.g. after you read `\r\n\r\n` sequence), you should send a response and decide if keep the connection open (see [`Connection: keep-alive` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Connection)) or close it.

Comment: With BufferedReader, you should use readLine() rather than character by character.

Comment: @MarcoLucidi Thanks a lot! I finally solved the problem with your help.

Comment: @Sako You should write something up as an answer, explaining how it works. Then you can accept it.